# Can't get result of FBSDKGameRequestDialog, FBSDK 4.0.1

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm sending lives to other players using the `FBSDKGameRequestDialog` and want to find out if the user sent them or canceled the request.
I've implemented the `FBSDKGameRequestDialogDelegate` but the methods are unreachable.

The code for the request is as follows:

```
    FBSDKGameRequestDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKGameRequestDialog alloc] init];
    dialog.delegate = self;
    dialog.content = gameRequestContent;
    dialog.frictionlessRequestsEnabled = YES;
    [dialog show];
```

Pretty basic tutorial dialog. From here on I have no feedback about the user actions.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate defined as a weak referance, so you should declare the dialog globally, not locally.

Just define it as a property, everything should be fine.

Comment: could you post the code example for this answer? I have the same issue.